# RSA Encryption - Finding P and Q

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to figure out an RSA Encryption (using Java) by finding out P and Q. Here is what I have to do:

I have to generate two random numbers (P and Q) and following the guidelines:

1. P & Q has to be at the most 7 bits long
2. P & Q cannot be 0 or 1 (**Using the Math.random() function is what I'm doing for this step**)
3. P & Q must be primes
4. P & Q cannot be the same number (**Already have this figured out**)
5. (PQ) must be at least 256 (**Already have this figured out**)

So, basically I'm starting out with this:

```
    double p = Math.random();
    double q = Math.random();
```

... and then trying to follow the 5 guidelines above. Can anyone give me a hint on how to figure out #1 and #3?

Thanks!

Comment: Using plain Random for p and/or q is useless, because you need PRIME numbers. Therefore start with method for detecting if some number is prime number or even with method for generating prime numbers.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr This looks like a homework problem, so that probably won't help.

Comment: for homework: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/71/how-can-i-generate-large-prime-numbers-for-rsa

Comment: as a note, you need integer. `random()` returns double, it doesn't help. very often, two keys used in RSA are too large for `long`. a special class is essential.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Miller-Rabin is a great tool but it's just... a bit too much for such a toy example.

Comment: If P and Q have to be *at most* 7 bits, find a list of primes using google and initialize an array of primes. There are only 31 prime numbers less than 128. Choose from those until you have what you need. Cf. http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/1000.txt

Comment: @JimFlood I'd prefer the 'generate random number of expected size and check if it's prime' approach since it's closer RSA is implemented with bigger numbers.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes, it's a better exercise. You could also be careful then not to have P and Q too close to each other. See this answer for more info: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5262/rsa-and-prime-difference

Answer (score 1):

`P` and `Q` must be greater than 1 and at most 7 bits, that is to say, smaller than `2^7 = 128`. Simply, generate a number between 2 and 127 inclusive.

For this purpose, you should use `Random.nextInt`, since it already gives you a random integer in a specified interval. Decide an upper bound for the random integers and you are set:

```
final Random rand = new Random();
int p = rand.nextInt(127 - 2 + 1) + 2;
```

Then, back to the core: the primality test. There are a few strategies for testing if a number is prime, but since your numbers are small we won't overcomplicate the thing and use a trial division. That is, try each (odd) number smaller than `P` and see if it evenly divides `P`:

```
public boolean isPrime(int p) {
    if (p == 2) return true;
    if (p % 2 == 0) return false;

    for (int d = 3; d < p; d += 2) {
        if (p % d == 0) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

there are a few optimizations possible here, like if there is a divisor of `P`, then it can't be larger than `Math.sqrt(p)`, but, I'll let you figure out the details.

So now you can put the two pieces together and get a prime number generator:

```
class PrimeGenerator {
    private final Random rand = new Random();

    public int next() {
        int p = nextInt();
        while (!isPrime(p)) {
            p = nextInt();
        }
        return p;
    }

    private int nextInt() {
        return rand.nextInt(127 - 2 + 1) + 2;
    }

    private boolean isPrime(int p) {
        // As above...
    }
}
```

The key point is generating a random number in the given range, testing if it is prime or not and repeating until a prime is generated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Seive of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), to check if a number is prime.

What you can do is, generate a list of all prime numbers (which the seive helps build easily) less than `2^7` - so that condition #1 is maintained. Then pick 2 numbers, `p` and `q`, at random from the list.

Here's how to build a list of primes using the seive:

```
List<Integer> getPrimeList(final int MAX_PRIME) {
    // Initialize a boolean array and set all values to true.
    bool[] isPrime = new bool[MAX_PRIME + 1];
    Arrays.fill(isPrime, true);

    List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();

    // Start from 2. 0 and 1 are not prime.
    for(int i = 2; i * i <= MAX_PRIME; i++) {
        // If we've found a prime, set all it's multiples as composite,
        // and add this prime number to the list.
        if(isPrime[i]) {
            for(int j = i * i; j <= MAX_PRIME; j += i) isPrime[j] = false;
            primes.add(i);
        }
    }

    return primes;
}
```

You can generate this list once, and use it every time you need to get a random prime number.

```
int getRandomPrime() {
    int randIndex = (int)(Math.random() * primes.size());
    return primes.get(randIndex);
}
```